# VBA- creating variable multiple

Tags: vba, excel

So new to coding completely. here is question :

How do I make a code that finds a multiple of a number within a set.

Ex. I have a set of number:  I want to order the number beginning with the first number with every pair that is 14 a part. I was able to figure out how to do this (See code below) But now I want to do another code looking for multiples of 14 so.. It would look at x, and then find (x*14), (x*(2*14)), etc.. Any help would be appreciated

Column A   Column B

459
452
426
485
425

```
Sub GetPairs()

      Dim x, z As Single
      Dim lastrow, pasterow As Single
      Dim testMass, nomMass As Single
      lastrow = Worksheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

    pasterow = 2



    For x = 2 To lastrow
        nomMass = Cells(x, 2).Value
        testMass = Cells(x, 2) + 14



o

    r z = 2 To lastrow
          If Cells(z, 2).Value = testMass Then
            Cells(pasterow, 7).Value = nomMass
            Cells(pasterow, 8).Value = Cells(z, 2).Value
            pasterow = pasterow + 1
          End If


     Next z

      Next x


End Sub
```

Comment: Your code needs to be edited as parts are missing. Use the edit feature.

Comment: Nothing to do with the question, but be aware that "Dim x, z As Single" results in x being a variant and z being a single. You are declaring them wrong it has to be "Dim x As Single, z As Single" to get what I think your are intending to do.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it should be that simple.

```
multiple = Cells(x*14, 2)
```

I think that should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Yes That worked perfectly.
Here is the final code I came up with :

Sub GetPairs()
 ``Dim x As Single, z As Single

`Dim lastRow, pasterow As Single`
Dim testMass, nomMass As Single
 `` Dim lastValue As Long
 `  Dim colCounter As Long

```
``Dim lookUpRange As Range

`lastRow = Worksheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
`lastValue = Worksheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Value
`Set lookUpRange = Worksheets(1).Range("B2:B" & lastRow)
```

``pasterow = 2

`For x = 2 To lastRow
   nomMass = Cells(x, 2).Value ' base value
    colCounter = 3

```
For z = Round((nomMass + 14), 0) To Round((lastValue + 14), 0) Step 14
    If Found(lookUpRange, z) Then
        'found
        Worksheets(1).Cells(x, colCounter) = z
        colCounter = colCounter + 1
    End If
Next z
```

Next x

End Sub

Private Function Found(rng As Range, valueToFind) As Boolean
    On Error GoTo errHandler

```
Dim v

v = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(valueToFind, rng, 1, 0)

Found = True
```